# Django - tastypie - jqgrid Wrapper (installation - manual)

Tags: django, jqgrid, tastypie

I would like to use the [following wrapper](https://bitbucket.org/migajek/django-tastypie-jqgrid) in one of my Django models, but unfortunately i do not know how to do it due to the lack of sufficient information. I run on my machine Djnago 1.9, tastypi via easy_install, Apache via mod_wsgi and MySQL.
After installing all these i do not know how to proceed step 1, step 2 etc in order to use the demo code mentioned in the above page and finally work successfully. Further details about the type of fields and how could be used in grids.py (additional information) would help me a lot. I found the author's [github page](https://github.com/migajek) but unfortunately there is no contact information to get in touch with him.

If anyone knows so much about it, i would be delighted!

Regards

Comment: !. You can find a git author's email by looking at their commits.

Comment: 2. That project says it's pre-alpha and it hasn't been updated in 3+ years. Using it might be a bad idea.